# Android UPDATE statement throwing SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: android, sql-update

I have a table for my app in SQLite DB in Android. E.g.

```
EMPLOYEE_DETAILS{
_ID      "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
NAME     "TEXT  NOT NULL",
SALARY   "INTEGER"
}
```

A record is correctly inserted for all 3 values using insert method.Now I'm trying to update the row SALARY field with a new value for a particular ID.I have created CONTENT VALUES object with just the SALARY field.
like -

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("SALARY",100000);
String[] arg = new String[1];
arg[0]="1"
db.update("EMPLOYEE_DETAILS", cv, "_ID=?",arg);
```

This update statement throws -

```
"SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed for NAME field"
```

even though the table already has a value for the given row in the name field and I'm not including the NAME field in the ContentValue during the update.

I can remove this exception by including the NAME field in the CV with original value as I don't intend to change the NAME field but the question is - Is this correct way?

Do I need to include all fields having **'not null'** constraints in the ContentValue even though I'm may not be updating these fields?

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8040466/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar I fail to see how that's relevent to this question

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line `String arg = new String[1];`

Comment: @AbuYousuf - I'm passing the argument to the where clause like where _ID=1

Comment: @HemantParmar - I didn't find anything relevant to my question in your link

Comment: assigning a String array to a String variable ?

Comment: @AbuYousuf - I have edited the post String[] args = new String[1]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue.
The code snippet I provided above was just a sample easy to understand one. The actual logic is more complex one.

The problem was completely with my code. Some where my flow was reaching the logic where I'm inserting the row using insert statement and not the intended code to update statement. I have corrected my logic and I confirm that the update Statement works properly no need to add the fields (with not null constraints).

The update statement works correctly by just adding the required fields.

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();        
    ContentValues cv;
    cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("NAME", "PRAMOD"); //NAME is of type "TEXT NOT NULL"
    cv.put("SALARY", 50000);
    db.insert("EMPLOYEE_DETAILS", null, cv);

    cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("SALARY", 70000);
    db.update("EMPLOYEE_DETAILS", cv, "_ID=?",new String[] {"1"});//this works as expected
```

Thanks for all your support.